# Determine all real numbers x > 0 for which log equation is true.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Determine all real numbers x > 0 for which
>   $$\log_4 x - \log_x 16 = \frac{7}{6} - \log_x 8$$

Attemp at solution:

$$\frac{1}{\log_x 4} -\log_x 16 + \log_x 8 = \frac{7}{6}$$
$$\frac{1}{\log_x 4} + \log_x \frac{8}{16} = \frac{7}{6}$$
$$\frac{1+\log_x \frac{1}{2} \cdot \log_x 4}{\log_x 4}  = \frac{7}{6}$$
$$\frac{1+(-2\log_x 2\cdot \log_x 2 )}{\log_x 4}  = \frac{7}{6}$$
$$\frac{1+(-2\log_x 2\cdot \log_x 2 )}{2\log_x 2}  = \frac{7}{6}$$
Not sure how to solve further

Comment: You are almost there: use $y=\log_x2$ and solve the quadratic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-2{(\log_x2) }^2=\frac73\cdot \log_x2$

Solve the resulting quadratic using $y= \log_x2$
$$1-2y^2=\frac73y$$
$$2y^2 +\frac73y-1=0$$
$$6y^2+7y-3=0$$
$$6y^2 +9y-2y-3=0$$
$$(3y-1)(2y+3)=0$$
Which gives 
$$x=2^{-2/3} or \ \ x=8$$

Comment: Why is it $\frac{7}{3\cdot \log_x 2}$ instead of $\frac{7\cdot \log_x 2}{3}$?

Comment: @lakada... It was correct but it looked like it was  in the denominator.... I edited it now...

Comment: [This solution](http://i.imgur.com/GO0tpkl.png) got a different answer. Not sure if I did something wrong in the original post.

Comment: No... Both answers match check them

Comment: Ok nice they match, I didn't know that different quadratics can have the same answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
u=\ln x,
$$
then the original equation becomes
$$
\dfrac{u}{2\ln2}-\dfrac{4\ln2}{u}=\dfrac76-\dfrac{3\ln2}{u},
$$
i.e.
$$
3u^2-(7\ln2)u-6(\ln2)^2=0.
$$
Then solution are
$$
u=\dfrac{7\ln2\pm\sqrt{49(\ln2)^2+72(\ln2)^2}}{6}=\dfrac{7\ln2\pm11\ln2}{6}=-\dfrac23\ln2,3\ln2=\ln2^{-2/3},\ln8.
$$
Hence
$$
x=2^{-2/3},8.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering the more general case $$\log_a( x) - \log_x(b) = c - \log_x(d)$$ and transform each logarithm to base $e$. This will give $$\frac{\log (x)}{\log (a)}-\frac{\log (b)}{\log (x)}=c-\frac{\log (d)}{\log (x)}$$ Define $\log(x)=y$ to get 
$$\frac{y}{\log (a)}-\frac{\log (b)}{y}=c-\frac{\log (d)}{y}$$ This will lead to $$y^2-c  \log (a)\,y+\log (a) \log \left(\frac db\right)=0$$ which may have $0,1,2$ solution in the real domain depending on the value of $$\Delta=\log(a)\left(c^2\log(a)-4\log \left(\frac db\right)\right)$$